# How I can get IP black list with APIs

Tags: email, dnsbl

I can get whether my IPs are in some black lists, such as DNSBL. But Is there any API that I can do the same work with it. Especially, I don't want the HTML text, I just want know where my IPs is in a black list, for example "127.0.0.1 YES".
Who can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **don't need an API to check blacklists**.

It's a simple dns query for the blacklist dns zone like `zen.spamhaus.org`

**Example**:

to query ip 10.11.12.13 in dns blacklists you will perform the dns query from (reverse IP) + blacklist zone name.

in our example the query will be 13.12.11.10.zen.spamhaus.org if the result is 127.0.0.2 then it's blacklisted else it's not blacklisted

find a complete working example and dnsbl lists [here](http://www.adminkit.net/dnsbl.aspx)